# How to fill datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server

I trying to fill a datatable in a foreach loop but it is not working.my code is

```
 @helper PrintProductYearChart(IEnumerable<DynamicNode> products)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (var prd in products)
        {
            var query = "SELECT DISTINCT year(AddedDate) FROM Product WHERE PID='" + prd.Id + "' ORDER BY year(AddedDate) DESC";
            SqlDataReader reader = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(umbraco.GlobalSettings.DbDSN, CommandType.Text, query);
            dt.Load(reader);
        }
    }
```

can anyone help.Thanks

Comment: Well, _it is not working_ is really a useless info. What is not working? Any error message?

Comment: no data added to datatable

Comment: If you run that query on Management Studio, do you get any results? And, are you sure the column PID is a string?

Comment: Why don't you use sql-parameters? Have you verified that there are years that should be returned?